# Cannot Start Apache2?

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I'm trying to install apache2 (To set up a LAMP stack), but something appears to be using the HTTP port on `0.0.0.0:80`.

There is also a text post about not being able to determine the server's fully qualified name.

Here is the full post:

```
invoke-rc.d: initscript apache2, action "start" failed.
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-05-22 15:57:55 UTC; 10ms ago
  Process: 28139 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 192.168.1.222. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: Action 'start' failed.
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 apachectl[28139]: The Apache error log may have more information.
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
May 22 15:57:55 scilab_comp_0 systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-21) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (237-3ubuntu10.21) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for ufw (0.36-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) ...
Rules updated for profile 'OpenSSH'
```

With regards to the server's domain name. I just created a domain name for it using my router's function for DDNS and have made this server a DMZ by forwarding all ports to it.

How should I go about resolving the issue and get Apache to start?

**EDIT 0:**

```
sarah@scilab_comp_0:~$ sudo netstat -tlpn | grep :80
tcp6       0      0 :::80            :::*              LISTEN      3034/httpd
```

Comment: It's more or less an duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1144848/653515). Run `sudo netstat -tlpn | grep :80` and figure what is listening on port 80 today. Stop/disable that service, and start Apache.

Comment: httpd is apache2...though that is how it is named on Red Hat flavors of linux.

Comment: @vidarlo It appears to be `httpd`. Hmm, no idea why/how the red hat version is present. How would I uninstall it? I ran `sudo purge apache2` already.

Comment: Can you run `uname -a` and post that here

Comment: @rtaft `Linux scilab_comp_0 4.15.0-50-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon May 6 18:46:08 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` I also purged apache* and attempted reinstall. This didn't help.

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep httpd`

Comment: @rtaft Returns nothing

Comment: well for now, `sudo service httpd stop` should get you around the issue, and `sudo systemctl disable httpd` to disable it, figure out how to remove it later.

Comment: `httpd` is typically the name you'd end up with if you install from source or similar. Are you sure you haven't installed apache previously, via some other method?

Comment: Within Ubuntu 16+ Apache2 (from the default repository) is named `apache2` and the binary is `/usr/sbin/apache2`, so apparently this service `httpd` probably is another HTTPD service, but not Apache2, so try to find which is it (by using `ps -aux | grep -i 'httpd'` or `which httpd`) and stop and disable it (if you do not need it) then restart Apache2. In order to suppress the message `AH00558:`  just add the directive `ServerName <put here your primary domain or ip without the brackets>` at the bottom of `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`.

Comment: What's the output of `which httpd`?

Comment: @vidarlo No output.

Comment: Looks like it's `nextcloud` from the output of `ps -aux | grep -i 'httpd'`. That doesn't make much sense to me though. Aren't they supposed to work in parallel? I followed a guide on it and they didn't mention anything about something like this.

Comment: @SarahSzabo How did you install nextcloud? You can't have two processes on listening to the same port, but Apache can host multiple websites, and act as a proxy for a server running on some other port, if needed.

Comment: @vidarlo I just ran `sudo snap install nextcloud` That was pretty much all aside for creating a user.

Comment: I would find how to change the listen port of `nextcloud`, then will setup my Apache, and as lat step will use proxy pass to access `nextcloud` via Apache's virtual host.

Comment: @SarahSzabo I don't touch snaps, but generally I'd recomend moving the snap's http server to a different port, and use `mod_proxy` in Apache to forward traffic, or set up nextcloud as a site in Apache.

Comment: After using `sudo snap disable` I reinstalled apache and it worked. I can't see the nextcloud page now when I type in the domain address, but that's a separate issue. I can see the Apache default page now.

Comment: Great! @vidarlo, could you write an answer?

Comment: @pa4080 Never touched a snap, and don't plan to :)

Answer (score 1):

you can see all the processes that are using port 80 at the time you are starting apache2 :

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:80
```

and also I think the easiest way to resolve the problem you are facing is to change your port to something else ,
you can change them in this two files in your apache 2 configs:

```
/etc/apache2/ports.conf 
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

after these you should restart the apache2 with this command :

```
 sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

also for getting better result you can run this command to see whats missing or making problem in starting apache2:

```
 systemctl status apache2.service
```

Comment: Changing the port off of 80 won't negatively affect people wanting to connect to it? I'm still learning how this works. Thanks for the post!

Comment: @SarahSzabo I had this error yesterday and with all the searches I came up with this solution and that worked for me , hope it works for you too

Comment: @SarahSzabo Using a non-standard port will affect users, yes. If it's public-facing, you should *probably* look into using TLS as well...

Comment: @SarahSzabo you can also find which process is using (listening) port 80 so you can kill the process , this one worked for me too.